# how to get variable substitution work with ansible api?

Tags: python, ansible

I simply want to parse the ansible inventory and get the variable values. Here is an example ansible project:

```
├── inventory
│   ├── hosts.yml
└── show_vars.yml
```

the hosts.yml:

```yaml
all:
  children:
    local:
      hosts:
        localhost:
          ansible_connection: local
  vars:
    var01: "example value01"
    var02: "example value02"
    var_sub01: "var01 is {{var01}}"
    var_sub02: "var02: {{var02}}; var01: {{var01}}"
    var_sub03: "var_sub01 is {{var_sub01}}"
    list01:
      - a
      - '{{ var01 }}'
    dict01:
      a: 1
      b: "{{ var02 }}"
```

the show_vars.yml

```
- hosts: all
  connection: local

  vars:
    save_hostvars_to_dir: "/tmp"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{hostvars[ansible_host]}}"
    - copy:
        content: "{{hostvars[ansible_host]}}"
        dest: "{{save_hostvars_to_dir}}/{{ansible_host}}.hostvars.json"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

I try to use the ansible api like this:

```py
import os
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
def get_host_vars_via_api(host_name: str, ansible_dir: str):
    loader = DataLoader()
    inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=os.path.join(ansible_dir, 'inventory'))
    var_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)
    return var_manager.get_vars(host=inventory.get_host(host_name))
```

When I use the function I get:

```py
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(get_host_vars_via_api('localhost', './'))

{'ansible_version': 'Unknown',
 'group_names': ['local'],
 'groups': {'all': ['localhost'], 'local': ['localhost'], 'ungrouped': []},
 ...
 'var01': 'example value01',
 'var02': 'example value02',
 'var_sub01': 'var01 is {{var01}}',
 'var_sub02': 'var02: {{var02}}; var01: {{var01}}',
 'var_sub03': 'var_sub01 is {{var_sub01}}'}
 'list01': ['a', '{{ var01 }}']
 'dict01': {'a': 1, 'b': '{{ var02 }}'}
```

The substitution does not happen right here. How do I expand the variables with ansible api?

thanks to @jakob3xd Templar is the answer:

```
import os
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.template import Templar

def get_host_vars_via_api(host_name: str, ansible_dir: str):
    loader = DataLoader()
    loader.set_basedir(ansible_dir)
    inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=os.path.join(ansible_dir, 'inventory'))
    var_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)
    vars = var_manager.get_vars(host=inventory.get_host(host_name))
    templar = Templar(loader=loader, variables=vars)
    for k, v in vars.items():
        vars[k] = templar.template(v)
    return vars
```

result is perfect:

```
{'ansible_config_file': '/tmp/ansible.cfg',
 'ansible_connection': 'local',
 'ansible_facts': {},
 'ansible_playbook_python': '/bin/python3',
 'ansible_version': 'Unknown',
 'dict01': {'a': 1, 'b': 'example value02'},
 'group_names': ['local'],
 'groups': {'all': ['localhost'], 'local': ['localhost'], 'ungrouped': []},
 'inventory_dir': '/tmp/test/inventory',
 'inventory_file': '/tmp/test/inventory/hosts.yml',
 'inventory_hostname': 'localhost',
 'inventory_hostname_short': 'localhost',
 'list01': ['a', 'example value01'],
 'omit': '__omit_place_holder__2d6dca0470017eb5803fe73c6f1cf37ea11b3885',
 'playbook_dir': '/tmp/test',
 'var01': 'example value01',
 'var02': 'example value02',
 'var_sub01': 'var01 is example value01',
 'var_sub02': 'var02: example value02; var01: example value01',
 'var_sub03': 'var_sub01 is var01 is example value01'}
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/ADAGpPnjI7Y/m/qlgn-fS1AwAJ) you can use [ansible Templar](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/1f9836fe9a417dd4dec9fcc7c7d45a11ee831d1f/lib/ansible/template/__init__.py#L576) to resolve the vars.

```
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.parsing.yaml.objects import AnsibleUnicode
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.template import Templar
from ansible.cli import CLI
from ansible import constants as C
import copy, os
from pprint import pprint
def get_host_vars_via_api(host_name: str, ansible_dir: str):
    loader = DataLoader()
    loader.set_basedir('./')
    # add vault secret to loader
    secret = CLI.setup_vault_secrets(loader=loader, vault_ids=C.DEFAULT_VAULT_IDENTITY_LIST)
    loader.set_vault_secrets(secret)
    inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=os.path.join(ansible_dir, 'inventory'))
    variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)
    selectedhost = inventory.get_host(host_name)
    hostvars = variable_manager.get_vars(host=selectedhost)
    templar = Templar(loader=loader, variables=hostvars)
    for k, v in hostvars.items():
        if (type(v) == str and '{{' in v and '}}' in v ) or type(v) == AnsibleUnicode:
            if 'hostvars' in v or 'ansible_default' in v:
                continue
            hostvars[k] = templar.template(v)
    return hostvars
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. THe Templar is the way to go. However, your code does not really work and have lots of unused lines. If you fix it I will accept your answer. There also some errors: 1 you should not just template when it is string. We want to expand everything. 2. there is no need for deepcopy

Answer (score 1):

If you struggle with using **collection plugin** **filters** in variable substitution (render) after upgrading from **ansible-base** to **ansible-core** try initializing plugin loader with **[init_plugin_loader](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/8a5ccc9d63ab528b579c14c4519c70c6838c7d6c/lib/ansible/plugins/loader.py#L1481)** function. See modified example from the topic below.

```
import os
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.plugins.loader import init_plugin_loader
from ansible.template import Templar

def get_host_vars_via_api(host_name: str, ansible_dir: str):
    init_plugin_loader()
    loader = DataLoader()
    loader.set_basedir(ansible_dir)
    inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=os.path.join(ansible_dir, 'inventory'))
    var_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)
    vars = var_manager.get_vars(host=inventory.get_host(host_name))
    templar = Templar(loader=loader, variables=vars)
    for k, v in vars.items():
        vars[k] = templar.template(v)
    return vars
```

works for ansible-core==2.15.3

p.s.
Use at your own risk.

p.p.s
Don't ask me how I found that.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible does not do jinja2 evaluation (and thus variable resolution) in any vars file, which includes inventory files. It will however do *recursive* jinja2 evaluation upon trying to use those variables, which may make it seem as though the vars file was evaluated upon load

One can see that by *using* the variable without having ansible *touch* it; create a hello-world-y vars file

```yaml
# sample.yaml
hello: "{{ ansible_version }}"
```

and then show the two different outcomes:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
  - sample.yaml
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: the hello from vars is {{ vars.hello }}
  - debug:
      msg: the hello in use is {{ hello }}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But to really answer my question is how can I use the ansible api to do the recursive jinjia2 evaluation with all the ansible filters/plugins?

Answer (score 0):

As Ansible does not do jinja2 evaluation on vars, you'll have to evaluate these values first from a playbook or other way and then populate the new inventory file with the contents you just evaluated.